# Put something in the middle of an url

Tags: url, hyperlink, lang

I would like to put something in the middle of an url for example this is my current link:

```
http://www.sitename.com/category/article
```

---

now I would like to put something directly in the middle, not replacing the link or putting it at the end, just like:

```
http://www.sitename.com/language/category/article
```

---

If possible I would like to have a pure html/php solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I've found my own way: breaking up the Url with explode() adding a new key in the array and implode() it back together. I was hoping for an easier way but i compacted it as much as possible